# Action needs to recognize dynamic items in an {{#each}} list

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, action

I have an action attached to a list item that is then looped through a number of times and I want that action to recognize which list item it is attached to.

This is the definition of the action. Notice that I've misused this.$() since i now recognize that it only works with components

View:

```
actions: {
    turnThisGreen:function() {
    this.$().css('background-color', 'green');
  }
}
```

And here is where i place the action in the loop. Let's assume there are 10 listItems.

```
{{#each listItems}}   
  <div {{action 'turnThisGreen' target="view" this=this bubbles=false}} class="inspectionTypeHeader">
    {{inspectionType.typeName}}
  </div> 
{{/each}}
```

So just to reiterate, when i click the action 'turnThisGreen', I want that element, meaning the 1 element ive clicked on out of the 10 listed, to turn green. this.$() is not doing it for me though.

I know that this.$() works with components but that seems like a massive work-around.

Can someone explain this to me and provide a solution?

Comment: Use objectController for the iterated items.

Comment: as in load the action's definition into the objectcontroller instead of the view, and use this.$() to call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you're encountering is that Ember makes it purposely difficult to do direct DOM manipulation. More often than not, you shouldn't be doing that. So assuming that this isn't a severe simplification of your real problem, you can change the color by binding a CSS class. As Hasib Mahmud said, [use an item controller](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each).

In your template:

```
{{#each listItems itemController='listItem'}}
    <div {{action 'turnGreen'}} {{bind-attr class='isGreen:green'}}>
        {{inspectionType.typeName}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

And your controller should look something like this:

```
App.ListItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isGreen: false,
    actions: {
        turnGreen: function() {
            this.set('isGreen', true);
        }
    }
});
```

This way, any time you trigger the action, the `green` class will be added to your `div`, which you can then use to turn your text green with CSS.